# AngularJS google Chart : ChartRangeFilter

Tags: javascript, angularjs, charts, google-visualization

I am using [AngularJS Google Chart](http://bouil.github.io/angular-google-chart/#/fat) to display a [line chart](http://bouil.github.io/angular-google-chart/#/fat).

I was reading about [ChartRangeFilter](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/controls#chartrangefilter) and need to use it in my graph. Is it possible to integrate the range filter from within [AngularJs Google Chart](http://bouil.github.io/angular-google-chart/#/fat)? or it doesn't have this feature supported yet?

I couldn't find any tutorial/documentations about this topic, so any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, it's not supported yet: [there's a feature request and a few discussion about it](https://github.com/bouil/angular-google-chart/issues/54).

Furthermore, it appears that it has an [attempt to support it, but it still needs revision, and probably some work](https://github.com/bouil/angular-google-chart/pull/141).

I think it would be a great opportunity for anyone interested on it to test and contribute.

Comment: can you please see my question maybe you would have an idea http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37256487/i-want-to-change-the-chart-for-each-city-or-subcity-selected